# CSS image size to fit nested div

Tags: html, css, image

I am trying to get an over sized image to scale to the size of a nested div. I have look at almost all of the Stack Questions that recommend setting max-width or max-height, but that does not work for my situation. Please see my code:

```css
#parent2 {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
#parent {
  height: 25%;
  width: 50%;
}
#parent img {
  max-height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div id="parent2">
  <div id="parent">
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/1000/1000">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: did you check the answer?

Answer (score 1):

You should use `max-width` and not `max-height`.

Here is a working example:

```css
#parent2 {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
#parent {
    height: 25%;
    width: 50%;
}
#parent img {
    max-width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div id="parent2">
  <div id="parent">
      <img src="http://lorempixel.com/1000/1000">
  </div>
</div>
```

Here is a fork to your jsfiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/358vt90e/

Answer (score 0):

try `background-size: cover;` instead of `max-height: 100%;`

https://jsfiddle.net/pq17nzfh/1/

Answer (score 0):

You can also use:

```
#parent img {
    width: inherit;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I added a bunch of different cases for you. Bear in mind object-fit has pretty bad browser support. You'll need polyfills if you want to use it.

```css
#parent2 {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
}
#parent {
  height: 25%;
  width: 50%;
}
#parent img {
  /* uncomment code below if you want image to respond to parent height */
  /*
  width: auto;
  height: 100%;
  */
  
  /* uncomment code below if you want image to respond to parent width */
  /*
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  */
  
  /* uncomment code below if you want image to respond to parent height and width */
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
  object-position: center;
}
```

```html
<div id="parent2">
  <div id="parent">
      <img src="http://lorempixel.com/1000/1000">
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

use

> max-width:100%;

```css
#parent2 {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}

#parent img {
   max-width:100%;
}
```

```html
<div id="parent2">
  <div id="parent">
      <img src="http://lorempixel.com/1000/1000">
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
#parent img {
    width: inherit;
}
```